# Project uses Log4j2 but dependency uses Log4j

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

We have a new project which we're writing using **Spring Boot** in which we're using **Log4j2** for our logging.

The problem is that we need to use an legacy library, which we own but we can't change; several other systems use it and we can't increase our scope by changing all of them.

When our project runs, it logs just fine using **Log4j2**, but when we make calls to the legacy library, it makes **Log4j** calls which throw exceptions.

**Is there a way to, in our new application which uses log4j2, handle the old log4j calls?**

---

### Update

Our legacy JAR contains several JARs in an internal lib folder including:

- log4j-1.2.6.jar

Our project is a Spring Boot project and we've included the dependency:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2

The log4j JARS that I see on the projects classpath are:

- spring-boot-starter-log4j2--1.5.9.RELEASE.jar
- log4j-slf4-impl-2.7.jar
- log4j-api-2.7.jar
- log4j-core-2.7.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `log4j-1.2-api` adapter? Use this together with the `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` dependencies. The adapter lets applications use the Log4j 1.2 API, but routes these calls to the log4j2 implementation. See the [which jars](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars) question in the FAQ.

If the application uses internal Log4j 1.2 classes this may not work but for plain logging it’s a drop-in replacement of the log4j-1.2.x jar.

Note that the legacy log4j-1.2.x jar should be ***removed*** from the classpath for this to work.

---

Update: if the legacy jar *contains* the Log4j 1.2.x jar and this causes the Log4j 1.2.x jar to be added to the classpath, the results are undefined.

I believe you have little choice but to create a custom version of this legacy jar ***without*** the Log4j 1.2.x jar. Other systems in your organization can continue to use the original legacy jar with the embedded Log4j 1.2.x jar, until they also want to migrate to Log4j2.

Your new version of the legacy jar (without embedded Log4j 1.2.x jar) may become the pathway to migrating to Log4j2 for all other systems in your organization.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm going to give it a try today. I've also updated my question with more details that I think are pertinent.

Comment: I updated my answer for the additional information in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I'm working with the team that manages that JAR to Maven-ize it. It's just a slow process working with other teams :(

Comment: I got pulled off of this project but I'm back on it, and adding the libraries that you recommended, and pulling out the original log4j JAR file from the legacy JAR worked.

Comment: Glad my answer was useful!